# Express TypeScript: Why is my controller method throwing error message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

folks. I'm just getting started with TypeScript and, thus, part of getting my feet wet includes converting a Express backend I built to TS. All has been well to this point, but now I got some rather unusual issues. Specifically, the lines `const hasVoted = poll.votedBy.some((voter): boolean => voter.equals(voterId));` and `const choice = await poll.choices.id(choiceId);` in the code snippet below, which result in `Property 'equals' does not exist on type 'string'` and `Property 'choices' does not exist on type 'Poll & Document'` error messages respectively. For reference, I has the JS version working just fine, so what is it that I may be missing here?

**Post Controller**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

import { Poll } from '../models/index';

class PollsController {
  public async addNewPoll(req: Request, res: Response) {
    // ...
  }

  public async voteInPoll(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { category, pollId } = req.params;
    const { name, choiceId, voterId } = req.body;

    try {
      const poll = await Poll.findById(pollId);

      // Check if user has already voted in poll
      const hasVoted = poll.votedBy.some((voter): boolean => voter.equals(voterId));

      if (!voterId) {
        res
          .status(401)
          .json({ message: 'Sorry, you must be logged in to vote' });
      } else if (voterId && hasVoted) {
        res
          .status(401)
          .json({ message: 'Sorry, you have already participated in poll' });
      } else {
        const choice = await poll.choices.id(choiceId);
        const votedChoice = { name, votes: choice.votes + 1 };

        await choice.set(votedChoice);
        await poll.votedBy.push(voterId);

        poll.save();

        res
          .status(200)
          .json({
            message: 'Thank you for voting.',
            poll,
          });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).json({ error });
    }
  }

  // ...
}

export default PollsController
```

**Poll Interface**

```
interface Poll {
  title: string;
  category: string;
  addedBy: string;
  votedBy?: [string];
}

export default Poll;
```

**Poll Schema**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

import PollInterface from './poll.interface';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ChoiceSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  votes: { type: Number }
});

const PollSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  category: { type: String },
  choices: [ChoiceSchema],
  addedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  votedBy: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
},{
    timestamps: true,
});

const Poll = mongoose.model<PollInterface & mongoose.Document>('Poll', PollSchema);

export default Poll;
```

**Edit**: Included both Poll interface and schema code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Property 'equals' does not exist on type 'string': if it works in JS, it mean voter is not a 'string' as you declared.

Check the signature of your method `Poll.findById(pollId)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, your interface defines `votedBy` as an array of strings.  You can call `.some` on an array but then you are calling `.equals` on a string which is not a method on type `string`.  You can change

```
const hasVoted = poll.votedBy.some((voter): boolean => voter.equals(voterId));
```

to

```
const hasVoted = poll.votedBy.some((voter): boolean => voter === voterId);
```

And the second one, you do not define `choices` on your `Poll` interface.  So the following line fails the typescript compiler because of it.

```
const choice = await poll.choices.id(choiceId);
```

You need to add `choices` as property on your `Poll` interface.  I don't know exactly what your implementation is but you would want to add something like the following to your `Poll` interface.

```
choices: {
  id:() => string;
}
```

From your code, it looks like you are trying to find a matching `choice` from a given `choiceId`.